# как в sublime text заменить символ с инкриментом

Tags: sublime-text, txt

```
txt_txt
ova_ava
text_tex
```

как вместо символа _ проинкриментить 1-2-3?

```
txt1txt
ova2ava
text3tex
```

Comment: Есть полу ручной вариант, если количество таких строк небольшое (будет интересно опишу), автоматически через регулярку там это не сделать, максимум есть плагин для нумерации строк.